# PowerShell Regex to extract timestamp

Tags: regex, powershell

```
$data = 'TimeStamp=2021-06-20 02:07:43.7841 Level=INFO TraceId=vQCGLkvAqFGEfrIR Message=End processing HTTP request after 7.5217ms - OK'

$test1 = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Matches($data , "(?<=TimeStamp=)[^\s]+").Value
```

Anyone know how to extract the full timestamp out of the string?. I only able to extract the date (2021-06-20).

i had tried another regex format(format2 as below) also, but it hit an error of (Exception calling "Matches" with "2" argument(s): "parsing "(?<=TimeStamp=)[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?.\d{3}\b)?]+" - Cannot include
class \d in character range.")

Format 2:

```
$test1 = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Matches($data , "(?<=TimeStamp=)[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?.\d{3}\b)?]+").Value
```

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: The pattern that you tried is wrapped in a character class, and the last digits should be 4 instead of 3 `(?<=TimeStamp=)\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{4}` See https://regex101.com/r/fqbtlz/1

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68064949/3832970) solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can match two non-whitespace chunks after `TimeStamp=`:

```
> $test1 = [regex]::Match($data , "(?<=TimeStamp=)\S+ \S+").Value
> $test1
2021-06-20 02:07:43.7841
```

Alternatively, you can also use

```
> $test1 = [regex]::Match($data , "(?<=TimeStamp=)\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{2}\.\d+").Value
> $test1
2021-06-20 02:07:43.7841
```

Note that since you want to get the first match only, you do not need `Regex.Matches`, you can use `Regex.Match`.

Another way to get the first match here is using `-match`:

```
> $data -match "(?<=TimeStamp=)\S+ \S+" | Out-Null
> $matches[0]
2021-06-20 02:07:43.7841
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can rely on all input strings to have the format shown in the question, a perhaps conceptually simpler alternative (though slightly slower) is to use **`-split`**, the regex-based [string-splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split):

```sh
# Sample input.
$data = 'TimeStamp=2021-06-20 02:07:43.7841 Level=INFO TraceId=vQCGLkvAqFGEfrIR Message=End processing HTTP request after 7.5217ms - OK'

# This outputs '2021-06-20 02:07:43.7841', as intended.
# Note: 
#  * -csplit is the case-*sensitive* variant of the case-insensitive -split
($data -csplit '^TimeStamp=| Level=')[1]
```